# Aspose subscription error

Tags: .net, aspose, aspose-cells

In one of our application we use Aspose.Cells (v 5.1.4.0) for excel generation. last day I was checking something and installed the latest version of the Aspose.Cells and now I am getting below error -

***The subscription included in this license allows free upgrades until 21 May 2011, but this version of the product was released on 15 Jul 2015. Please renew the subscription or use a previous version of the product.***

I have already un-installed the newer version but that did not help.. I also had a live chat with one of their support team member but they are asking to buy new subscription, and I can't do that.

do you guys have any idea how to fix this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very simply put, you cannot use your current license with the newest build. You will have to upgrade your license if you want to use the newest version of the product. I would suggest downloading the version that was released closest to May 21st, 2011. For uninstallation, make sure there aren't any Aspose references for the new version in your GAC, Program Files, etc. (maybe the uninstaller left some things hanging around). Delete any Aspose DLLs in your bin folders and update your project references. Even a reboot on a Windows machine could help.

Comment: I have removed the latest build from system, still get this error.

Comment: Check my updated comment -- I understand now the issue isn't the license itself, but that you're still getting this message even after uninstalling the new version.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to fix it by looking for any left outs after uninstallation latest version. I found out one of the project in my solution was also referencing Aspose (Sorry, I was not aware of it) . I just updated that reference with old dll and it fixed the issue.

@Cᴏʀʏ's suggestion helped me.

Thanks.